# Getting bean creation errors when creating a shared interface for my ReactiveCrudRepositories, is it possible to create share interfaces like this?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux, r2dbc

so my Kotlin / spring-boot application makes use of several reactiveCrudRepositories, and I am trying to reduce the amount of code I need to write methods that are common to each table in my database.

I was trying to create a common interface that each table implements, but am getting the following error when i build:

> Error creating bean with name 'sharedRepo' defined in com.*.*.sharedRepo defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on R2dbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguireRegistrar.EnableR2dbcRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of ini method failed; nested exception is in org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find persistentEntity for type class java.lang.Object!

I have tried reducing the complexity of the interface down to just an empty interface (so that i can still write generic methods) but this has not worked.. the following is what my code currently looks like:

itemA.kt

```
@Table(table_a)
data class itemA(

@Id
@Column("id")
val menuId: UUID

@Column("name")
val prodName: String

...
}

interface AClassRepository : sharedRepo<itemA>, Serializable
```

itemB.kt

```
@Table(table_b)
data class itemB(

@Id
@Column("id")
val menuId: UUID

@Column("name")
val prodName: String

...
}

interface BClassRepository : sharedRepo<itemB>, Serializable
```

SharedRepo.kt

```
interface sharedRepo<T> : ReactiveCrudRepository<T, UUID>
```

databaseAssistant.kt

```
fun <T> sharedRepo<T>.persist(item: T) = {
    Try {
       //this is calling the ReactiveCrudRepository.save method
       save  
     } ...
}
fun <T> sharedRepo<T>.someOtherDbCall(item: T, newName: String) = 
    *some other method body*
```

serviceC.kt

```
@Service
class ServiceC(
    private val repositoryA: AClassRepository,
    private val repositoryB: BClassRepository
( {
    
    fun useRepo() =
        repositoryB.persist(someInstanceOfItemA)

    fun useOtherRepo() = 
        repositoryA.someOtherDbCall(someInstanceOfItemB, "aNiceName")
}
```